# How to open the activity that launched a notification when clicked on it?

Tags: android

I want to open the activity that gave a notification and the user should be directed to the activity if s/he clicks on it. And the notification should disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this method for open activity in android

```
   // Notification Method
private void Notification(String notificationTitle,
        String notificationMessage) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    android.app.Notification notification = new android.app.Notification(
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Message from Binesh Kumar! (Android Developer)",
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, AndroidNotifications.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(AndroidNotifications.this,
            notificationTitle, notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(10001, notification);
}
```

Comment: Will this work because I already tried this. It will give a notification but I was not returned anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**1**. Create any notification something like

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =

    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

**2.** Now if you want to associate any activity say `ResultActivity` , create `PendingIntent`

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =

    PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this,
    0,
    resultIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);
```

**3:**   Set the pending intent to notification builder

```
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```